# display data in view that assign through model

Tags: angular, typescript

excuse me for my lack of understanding regarding this matter. so let me get to my problem. I create a model that contains an information like this.

```
export class Organization {
     orgId?: string;
     orgName: string;
     orgAddress: string;
}
```

and then I import it to my controller with my service to get my data.

```
import { Organization } from '../model/organization';
import { OrganizationService } from '../service/organization/organization.service';
```

so having said that. i set my model and services in order to get my data.

```
 organization: Organization


 ngOnInit() {
   this.orgSvc.getUserOrganization().subscribe(org => {
    this.organization = org.data();
    console.log(this.organization );   
 })
}
```

if I console.log the data. it will print out all the data that I need.

```
{
    orgId: 'sdfasfasdfcv',
    orgName: 'testOrg',
    orgAddress: 'street test'
 }
```

but everytime that I display it to my view. it get me an error of property of undefined.

```
{{ organization.orgName }}
```

what did i miss? I read the documentation of `angular io`. even if I create a new instance. like `this.organizationData = new Organization('', '', '' ... )` it doesn't work.

Comment: try to use `ngIf or typesafe ?` operator

Comment: That's happening because by the time Angular renders the view, your app didn't receive the organization data yet, so it is still undefined

Answer (score 2):

use typesafe **`?`** operator

```
{{ organization?.orgName }}
```

It is because the service call is made after the DOM is rendered. At the time of rendering the object is `undefined` when you are trying to access its properties it is not available. The above fix will prevent the initial error

More information **[read here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1303)**

Comment: its like you hacked it. is their any solutions? and thanks its working

Comment: Cool....... other solution use a `*ngIf` to check the object availability